# Repeat grok pattern

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, logstash-grok, grok

I have a message like this "Something word word 20/07/2018 word word 25/04/2015".How can I use a grok pattern or a customer pattern to take all dates and add them into a new field which is an array?

I tried with a custom regex pattern but when I specify the global flag, ES doesn't recognize "/g" flag.The problem is that I don't know how many dates I will have in a document because are invoices or other type of docuemtns which have a lot of dates/numbers inside.

Comment: Does the solution have to be implemented via a grok pattern or are other filter plugins also accepted?

Comment: I can use whatever solution you have. The idea is that I have to take all the dates from the text and insert them into a new field because at runtime I will give a date range and I want to find just the docuemnts which have a date between that range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have stated in the comment section that you are free in your implementation, I would solve this with logstashs ruby filter and with the help of this article:

https://zzamboni.org/post/capturing-multiple-matches-in-ruby/

(Sorry for not formatting the link but I'm on my mobile phone right now.)

The article describes how you match a string against a regex and store all found values in an array.

So the filter would look something like this (untested):

```
filter{
  ruby{
    code => '
      my_string = event.get("my_field") 
      my_array = my_string.scan(/[0-9]+\/[0-9]+\/[0-9]+/)
      event.set("my_array_field_name", my_array)
    '
  }
}
```

By playing around with this skeleton you should be able to solve the issue. Also take a look at the documentations.